# How to create a tip balloon?

Tags: ios

[Here is my image.I want to create a tip balloon like this.  This must visible when user types in textfield](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrgFn.jpg)

I have created one more but that is in cloud shape.  Please help to create this

Answer (score 2):

Subclass the `UITextField` then override `becomeFirstResponder` (show bubble) and `resignFirstResponder` (hide bubble) and when the field is active present your bubble.

**.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BubbleTextField : UITextField

@end
```

**.m**

```
#import "BubbleTextField.h"

@interface BubbleTextField ()
{
    UIView *_bubbleView;
}

- (void)showBubble:(BOOL)show;

@end

@implementation BubbleTextField

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialize the _bubbleView here
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Override

- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder {
    BOOL shouldBecome = [super becomeFirstResponder];

    if (shouldBecome)
    {
        [self showBubble:YES];
    }

    return shouldBecome;
}

- (BOOL)resignFirstResponder {
    BOOL shouldResign = [super resignFirstResponder];

    if (shouldResign)
    {
        [self showBubble:NO];
    }

    return shouldResign;
}

#pragma mark - Private Methods

- (void)showBubble:(BOOL)show {
    // Show/Hide
    // Animations etc.
}

@end
```

Comment: ,can you please give any example or code.

Comment: just edited my answer with some example code

Comment: Thanks to all.i got it and hope it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

- Check out **[KBPopupBubble](https://github.com/psholtz/KBPopupBubble)**.
- And **[CMPopTipView](https://github.com/chrismiles/CMPopTipView)**
- Also, check out these search results for custom controls on cocoa controls. **[Search Results](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=bubble)**.

Comment: This website is no more available

Comment: Here's another one: https://github.com/chrismiles/CMPopTipView

Comment: Ok, I updated the link for KBPopupBubble, but cocoa controls is not down for me, it's working fine.

@JasperBlues thanks for the link, I updated my answer.